# Should I recreate producer after ProducerFencedException?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-transactions-api

If I got `ProducerFencedException` in my transactional producer, should I try to recreate it?
If I got this exception, it means that there is another producer with the same `transaction.id`, but if a new producer is closed (replica is down), my old producer will not be recreated (but replica is still alive). So, I got in situation where I have no producer at all.
How is this usually decided? Creating sort of container for lifecycle? Can you provide some example?